# PHP If Variable isset add input with checkbox checked not working

Tags: php

I am having a problem with some code...

Here is the code:

```
<?php
if (isset($myVar)) {
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="ck1" id="ck1" checked />Checked/Not checked';
}
?>
```

I've tried checked, checked="checked" checked="true" ...but for some reason the checkbox doesn't come out checked.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page? The correct way is to write checked="checked", but there might be some other reasons, like some code on javascript :)

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: There is something wrong in the rest of the page. Your code, as it is, **[works](http://jsfiddle.net/tRFxq/)**. Maybe you are using some Javascript that change checked state of the input? Or you are accessing that page using browser Refresh button or F5 key (in these cases, all form state is preserved by browser)?

Comment: Are you using the correct MIME type for XHTML? Is that variable actually set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should workd...

try the following to debug

```
die("var->" . $myVar);
if().....
```

as for the checkbox....

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: I think that checkbox is rendered, but not checked.

Comment: @Cheery ah. well in the case even stranger :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be: checked="yes"

So `<input type="checkbox" name="ck1" id="ck1" checked="yes" />`

Comment: Simply having the `checked` attribute works but to be XHTML compliant  we write `checked = "checked"`

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten this to work in the past:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="value" <?php if($var == 'N'){echo 'checked'; }?> />
```